# Countdown Timer on Switch Input ARM 7

Tags: microcontroller, switches, arm, arm7

I have been trying to create a countdown timer using ARM7 micro-controller, once an switch input has been detected. So far I managed to create a delay function of 1 minute, and detect a switch input. However, once the switch is released, the countdown will stop.

First I have set up 2 Seven Segment displays which detect a switch input and can increment or decrement the minutes.

I have set the `delay_MINUTE` function as follows which is basically a 1 minute delay. I have checked this using an LED and this part of my program is working:

```
  void delay_MINUTE(void)
{
 T0TCR = 0x0;                   //Resetting Timer0

 T0MR0 = 499999;                //Loading match register value

 T0PR = 600;                  //Loading Prescalar register value  

 T0PC = T0TC = 0;             //The value in the register increments with   every     input pulse or Processor clock fed into it. 

 T0MCR = (1<<0) | (1<<2);     //Generates interrupt and reset on match.    

 T0TCR = 0x1;                   //Starting Timer

 while(!(T0IR & (1<<0)));       //Waiting for interrupt
 T0IR = (1<<0);               //Clearing interrupt
}
```

I am getting stuck in a simple part of the program. When a switch input is detected on P0.14, the current display should decrement by one, every one minute.

If I simply do:

```
     int y = 0;
     unsigned int SW3;
     if((SW3) == y)  //detecting switch input
    {
        delay_MINUTE();
        num_right --;
    }
```

the number will only decrease by one when the switch is pressed, and not keep on counting down until it reaches 0. Any suggestions on how I could change my code to detect one switch input and continuously decrement after it has been released would be appreciated.

**EDIT** I have also tried creating a for-loop inside the switch statement such that when the switch is pressed, the countdown will start depending on the current digit being displayed. I am not sure if this is a good idea or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> detect one switch input and continuously decrement after it has been released would be appreciated.

try this:

```
if (sw3_pressed()) 
  while (num_right--) delay_Minute();
```

Comment: Are you assuming a function here? I was detecting switch input just by using `if((SW3) == y)` or something of the sort